# Can't Get Barebones Ember Cli App to Display Items

Tags: ember.js

I'm learning ember and trying to use the guide to the main `application` template to display a list of items.

It's pretty simple so far. Here's what I've got:

**app/routes/application.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  model() {                                                                     
    return $.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');                  
  }                                                                             
});
```

**app/templates/application.hbs**

```
<ul>
{{#each controller as |item|}}
<li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

When the page loads, nothing is displayed even though I can see the http request was made.

I didn't create a controller because the [ember doc](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/getting-started/naming-conventions/) states that my route should return an `Ember.ArrayController`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I highly recommend you download [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) if you haven't already. It's a browser extension that's become almost mandatory for Ember development. It would be able to tell you if you're receiving the data you expect because I think it might be a problem in your template code.

Try `{{#each model as |item|}}` instead of `{{#each controller as |item|}}`.

Comment: Have the inspector, but using model instead of controller did the trick. Thanks!